# How do I configure a Huawei b520 ADSL router to work in bridge way?

Tags: bridge, adsl, bridge-router

I have a much better router now, Cisco e4200 but I still have to use the Huawei b520 router because the internet connection is using ADLS.

I want to configure b520 to act in a bridge mode and be transparent because I want to be able to access the Cisco e4200 from outside.

How do I configure this? - I don't need exact guide, I can read the manuals but ADSL is not in my area of knowledge.

So far I assumed that I need to set the Cisco to connect using PPPoE to the b520 but it will not connect.

In fact, I could redirect all the ports from b520 to the Cisco router but in this case the DynDNS feature of the Cisco is not going to work because it will have a private IP.

Comment: It's either in the manual or it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the manual (read the referenced parts on your own!):

### Configuring the Bridge Mode

To configure the Bridge mode for the WAN interface, do as follows:

1. Repeat from the step1 to the step 7 of 4.1.1 "Configuring the PPPoA Mode."
2. On the Connection Type page, select bridge. Keep other settings by the Internet Service
   Provider.
3. Click Next to show the *"Unselect the check box below to disable this WAN service"*
   page, keep the default settings. Make sure choose Data in the Service Name drop-down
   list box.
4. Click Next to show the *"WAN Setup-Summary"* page, click Save to save the settings.

Note: Click Back to make any modifications. Reboot the terminal so that the settings take effect.